# How to set iOS ScrollView in DetailViewControl?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, scrollview

[image: UI]

[image: Xcode]

You need a scroll view to implement it as shown in the picture above. But I don't know how to implement it. That's the only thing on the storyboard that's missing.

And when you run it, you just move the scroll bar next to the screen, and there's no change on the screen.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to deselect `Content Layout Guides`? [image]